# Tkinter Button Not Displaying until loop ends

Tags: python, button, tkinter, vpython

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
loop = True
loggedIn = False
vsbl = None#Assign None type
root = Tk()
Cube.displaying()
btn_rr = ttk.Button(root, text="right forward")
btn_rr.pack()
btn_rr.config(command = lambda: Cube.rotate_right("forward"))
while loop:
```

I am building a Rubik's Cube program - I want to add buttons. The module I am using is called VPython. Whether I place the buttons inside or outside the loop they won't display until I close the VPython window.

Comment: `while` and `sleep` block tkinters mainloop. This causes the GUI to freeze until they complete. You will have to refactor your code to use `after` or use  threading to handle your loop. That said please provide a testable example.

Comment: `tkinter` (like other GUI framework) has own loop - `root.mainloop()` - which has to run all time and if you run other loop then it blocks mainloop and it can't update/redraw widgets in window. You may have to run other loop in thread or you may try to use `after(milliseconds, function)` to run single loop periodically. Eventually you can use `root.update()` in other loop ro force tkinter to redraw/update window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to echo @furas comment about how `tkinter` has its own loop - `root.mainloop()`
If you are running code simultaneously with a `tk.raise()` or other `tkinter` modules, you will need to use the `root.update()`.

The more you stay away from needing these `root.update()` lines, the better, but sometimes it can't be avoided.